# Sending a Stream request in Network.HTTP.Conduit

Tags: haskell, conduit, http-conduit

I am sending a request this way:

```
import Network.HTTP.Conduit

request <- parseUrl url
res <- withManager $ httpLbs request
```

That being said, I want to send a stream request and then iterate over it. I haven't found any mention of `stream` in the documentation of `Network.HTTP.Conduit`.

How do I do this?

Comment: With great difficulty! (Well, it’s supposed to be clean and easy, but I’ve had some bad experience. Anyways…) [You’ll have to grab a conduit.](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-conduit-2.1.2.3/docs/Network-HTTP-Conduit.html#v:http) If you find it easier, though, [here’s what http-conduit is based off of](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-client-0.3.4/docs/Network-HTTP-Client.html).

Comment: @false, thanks. Is there any simple example? Should I use RequestBodyStreamChunked?